# What is the optimal way to use setInterval in jquery ajax calls?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I am using [JQWidgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxchart/index.htm) to create a pie chart. And while that is all fine and dandy and working like a charm. What I'd like to do however is update the data every x number of seconds. Using jQuery, here is the code that I have so far:

```
function loadChart(id,name){
   //chart loads here
   var speed = 5000,
       t = setInterval(reloadData,speed);
   function reloadData() {
        source.url = 'data.php?id='+id;
        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
        $('#pie').jqxChart({ source: dataAdapter });
        console.log('reloading pie...'+globalPieId);
        speed = 5000;
        clearInterval(t);
        t = setInterval(reloadData, speed);
    }
}
```

My issue is, that if the loadChart function is called, another instance of setInterval is created, and after three or four times, the chart is in a constant state of refresh. How do optimize my setInterval call so that only one instance is called?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using `setTimeout` instead and add a new timeout only when you've got the callback from the last call. (which you're already doing it would seem)

Comment: @lfxgroove hit the nail on the head. Ditch that `interval` and replace it with a `timeout`, should only be a few code changes and then you can get rid of that `clearInterval` since `timeout` takes care of it.

Comment: A fine explanation: http://reallifejs.com/brainchunks/repeated-events-timeout-or-interval/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear existing interval before you set up a new one. Try the following trick.

```js
function loadChart(id, name) {
    // We use a trick to make our 'interval' var kinda static inside the function.
    // Its value will not change between calls to loadChart().
    var interval = null;

    // This is the core of a trick: replace outer function with inner helper 
    // that remembers 'interval' in its scope.
    loadChart = realLoadChart;
    return realLoadChart(id, name);

    function realLoadChart(id, name) {
        var speed = 5000;

        // Remove old interval if it exists, then set up a new one
        interval && clearInterval(interval);
        interval = setInterval(reloadData, speed);

        function reloadData() {
            // ... your code, but no do nothing with interval here ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Though I do think that @lfxgroove's method would have worked in any other circumstance.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using `setInterval` which calls the function over and over again you would be better off using the `setTimeout` function which will call the callback you specify just once. Once that callback is called you can once again call `setTimeout` and you'll stop having the problems you're having right now. Also you'll wait until the last call is done before you start doing another one which is also good. The code might look something like this with the change:

```
function loadChart(id,name){
   //chart loads here
   var speed = 5000,
       t = setTimeout(reloadData,speed);
   function reloadData() {
        source.url = 'data.php?id='+id;
        var dataAdapter = new $.jqx.dataAdapter(source);
        $('#pie').jqxChart({ source: dataAdapter });
        console.log('reloading pie...'+globalPieId);
        speed = 5000;
        t = setTimeout(reloadData, speed);
    }
}
```

For a working poc you could see http://jsfiddle.net/9QFS2/

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just tried this and got the same issue as before. As soon as the loadChart function is called again with different parameters, the chart starts to refresh multiple times (in my case it was refreshing every 5 seconds twice with the two instances offset by 2 seconds)

Comment: How do you call `loadChart`?

Comment: This. `setInterval` is problematic, to say the least.

Comment: @lfxgroove loadChart is called when a button is clicked onClick='loadChart(1,'all')'

Comment: @Robusto tell me about it!

Comment: And you don't call it in any other place at all? :/ Because the reason for the problems popping up in the fiddle you've posted are that we call the function that sets the timeout twice.