# Ajax to display a file in 1-second intervals without user interaction

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, dom

I wanted to write an Ajax script to replace a DOM value/display the content of a file (which changes) in 1-second intervals, without having to hit any buttons to start it, how is it done? The file isn't complex, and might just contain a single number or string.

Lance

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict ;
use warnings ;
use CGI ;
package AjaxTest ;

my $PA = "position:absolute; " ;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang='en'>
        <head>
            <style type='text/css'>
                p.Standard{ font-family:helvetica ; font-size:14px ; text-decoration:none ; text-align:left ; text-indent:0ex ; white-space:nowrap ; }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div style='" . $PA . "left:2px ; top:2px ; '>
                <p id='ToChange' class='Standard'></p>
            </div>" ;
&OverviewAjax ;
print
       "</body>
    </html>" ;
exit ;

sub OverviewAjax {
    print
    "<script type='text/javascript'>
         setInterval( UpdateOverview , 500 ) ;

         function UpdateOverview() {
             document.getElementById('ToChange').innerHTML = JSGimme( 'TextFile' ) ;
         }

         function JSGimme( nit ) {
             jsiocb = fopen( 'files/' + nit , 0 ) ;
             if ( jsiocb != -1 ) {
                 length = flength( jsiocb ) ;
                 jsval = fread( jsiocb , length ) ;
             }
             fclose( jsiocb ) ;
             return jsval ;
         }
     </script>" ;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the `setInterval()` function?

Comment: All examples I found on the web, you have to click a button to start it.

Comment: so... just execute the code outside of an event. Not everything has to have an event. For example, `<script>alert("Hello World!");</script>` stop the copy/paste programming and start writing code!

Comment: So what this example is supposed to do is read the file called files/TextFile, and display it's contents every half second. Meanwhile, another program (not shown) is updating that file.

Comment: What is `fopen`? that's not perl code in javascript is it?

Comment: Forget about the setInterval and first figure out how to send and respond to an ajax request, you clearly don't understand how the server-client communication works.

Comment: Don't know - it's from an example I found on the web. I think it's specific to Microsoft somehow...

Answer (score -1):

Use `window.setInterval` to do it:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: You dont. Setinterval recieves a function and an interval in miliseconds. The function should do the ajax. Here's a good answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18987943/what-is-the-optimal-way-to-use-setinterval-in-jquery-ajax-calls

Comment: Like with any Javascript function, it can be fired at any time. If you want it to fire on document ready, set up the function to fire on document ready instead of on click.

Comment: I guess no one knows how to do this?

Comment: @user3550435 Plenty of people do. I do. but i'm not going to write your code for you. Give us a starting point.